# Sql update big amount of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to update big amount of rows, something like 100,000.
Probably one query would be too heavy to the server.

What is the best way to split the update?
Something like update 200 rows, sleep a sec, then another 200.

Edit:

Okay I got an answer that it would be okay to do it in one query.
But still I'd like to know how to do this.
Assume I have 1,000,000 rows or more.
What would be the best way to split the query?

Comment: I would upgrade your server if you cannot execute an update to 100k rows in one query. How many fields are you trying to update at a time? If it's a huge amount perhaps you need to rethink your schema.

Comment: What is your basis for thinking that updating 100K rows would be too heavy for the server?

Comment: An update should be atomic. What if the data changes during the sleep?

Comment: I need to update only one field. I just assume that such action may be heavy. I'm glad to know that it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there are constraints you didn't tell us, updating all in one query is the best solution.

Thinking about splitting stuff because of overloading the server seems of no real use. Just think about your own solution and numbers. If you have one million datasets, and you try to update them 200 at a time, then sleep one second, you end up doing 5000 Updates and spend 83.3 Minutes waiting for the server to finish this task, not counting the amount of time it takes to execute the query, which might be really quick.

Essentially you'd know or select all IDs in your database and send a query for each of them, or groups, by using an appropriate WHERE clause with the UPDATE.

Unless we know more about the scenario, this question cannot be answered. It deals with optimizing stuff for a very individual usage pattern, and no solution can be applied everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use combination from Limit and ORDER BY last_updated_time ASC...

Something as ...

```
UPDATE table SET ..... ORDER BY last_updated_time ASC LIMIT 5000
```

5000 updates usually aren't too havy.. if you want set it to 1000..